# Hatching over simple fill in ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, symbology, arcgis-10.3

I have a polygon layer that is symbolized into four categories. Two of these categories are above a threshold limit and two are below. I would like to further distinguish the two categories above the threshold limit but putting "10% simple hatch" OVER the polgyon fill colour from the colour ramp. How do I combine symbol layers so that a solid background colour appears under hatching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily using the symbol selector options, however it will need to be done for each symbol you want to change - it can't be done as part of the color ramp.

Click on **Edit Symbol...**
[image]

Click **Add Layer**
[image]

Move the new layer down below the 10% hatch layer
[image]

Change the symbol properties Type for this new layer to be Simple Fill Symbol, and select the desired color.
[image]